# HashBytes('MD5', SomeValue) returns wrong md5 hash

Tags: sql-server

I`m trying to crate view what will return md5 hashed value like suggested in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)
HashBytes return wrong value if I try to use column. For example:

```
select Value, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', 'test'),2) from SomeTable
```

result is 246A848AF2F8394E3ADBC738DBE43720

but when I try

```
select  Value, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', Value),2) from SomeTable
```

result for cell with Value test is C8059E2EC7419F590E79D7F1B774BFE6

Comment: are you converting Value to nvarhcar when you are passing to hashbytes method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'test'` is a `varchar`, not an `nvarchar`. Try

```
select Value, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', N'test'),2) from SomeTable
```

which returns `C8059E2EC7419F590E79D7F1B774BFE6` as you should expect.

Comment: C8059E2EC7419F590E79D7F1B774BFE6 is the wrong version :(

Comment: @SpoksST Why do you think that?

Comment: Because external provider returns md5 that maches first variant as well as this site http://www.adamek.biz/md5-generator.php

Comment: That returns '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' as does `HASHBYTES('md5',convert(varchar,value))`